Как в телеграм боте, используя модуль telebot, запретить сворачивание кнопок types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()?

На фото указана кнопка, при нажатии которой скрываются кнопки бота. Необходимо ее убрать, такая возможность есть, т.к. в некоторых ботах ее нет.

Используйте инлайн кнопки.
